# How to solve the error of data provider if only one browser is taking the complete input data?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to achieve parallel execution through data provider, but unable to do it. can someone help me with this.
The error is two browsers are opening but the data is going to only one browser.

Here, is my program code:

```
package PracticePrograms;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class DataProviderSample1{
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(6));   
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");

    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "inputData")
    public void testLogin(String UserName, String Password ) throws InterruptedException {
    
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(UserName);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name = "inputData", parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] loginData() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[2][2];
        data[0][0] = "Admin";
        data[0][1] = "admin123";

        data[1][0] = "admin";
        data[1][1] = "admin123";

        return data;
    }
    
     @AfterMethod
        public void tear_down() throws InterruptedException {
           driver.quit();            
        }  

}
```

I appreciate u r help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your method logic runs in parallel all your threads still use the same instance of your test class. Hence they share the same instance of your `driver` field.

This leads to the case when the `setUp()` executed "after" overwrites the value set by `setUp` that has been executed "before"..

So to overcome this you need to introduce `ThreadLocal` variable. Instead of `public WebDriver driver;` you would have `ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();`

Now instead of `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` you would have `driver.set( new FirefoxDriver());`

After you have set that driver to `ThreadLocal`, wherever you obtain its value you have to do `driver.get()`. For example:

```java
  driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
  driver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(6));   
  driver.get().get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
```

Comment: I appreciate you Alexey R, for explaining the cause of error and how to solve it . Definitely, I will follow your instructions and try to rectify it.

Comment: Alexey ,I did it successfully. I was struggling for the last few days to overcome this issue, finally I got it with your help, thanks a lot.